# Need a probability measure be able to assign probabilities to all outcomes in the sample space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Or put differently, can a sample space include outcomes that have no probability i.e. outcomes on which the probability measure is not defined (given there is a sigma-algebra of events that the probability measure is defined upon)?

Comment: of course it can if you consider the set of possible outcomes as the power set of the atomic outcomes, however in practice these cases doesn't appear often

Comment: Even though it is a requirement for a probability space that P(Ω)=1 (where P is the probability measure)? Doesn't that imply that P must be defined on all elements of Ω?

Comment: this is not generally possible, that $P$ is defined in all subsets of $\Omega$. By example consider the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, then, because the Lebesgue measure of $[0,1]$ is positive there exists some non Lebesgue measurable $A\subset [0,1]$, however the probability measure of an uniform distribution in $[0,1]$ is equivalent to the Lebesgue measure. You can consider $A$ as a possible outcome for some problem, however it is not possible to give a probability to this set, at least in the measure-theoretic sense

Comment: @cjkilimanjaro $P$ is technically defined on a collection of subsets of $\Omega$, namely, the $\sigma$-algebra which does not need to exhaust every possible subset.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your question with an example.
Consider $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\Omega\}$ on $\Omega$ and construct a probability measure $P$ by
$$P(\emptyset)=0 \quad ,\quad P(\{1,2\})=p \quad , \quad P(\{3,4\})=1-p \quad, \quad P(\Omega)=1$$
where $0\leq p \leq 1$. P is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, but $P(\{1\})$ is undefined.

Comment: In your example all outcomes in sample space can be found in the sigma-algebra. What if there exist outcomes in sample space that are not elements of any event in the sigma-algebra, could the probability measure still be defined (so that the requirement of P(Ω) = 1 is still meet)??

Comment: Such a sigma-algebra is not possible, since $\Omega$ is in the sigma algebra.
Also if $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and $\omega$ is an element not in A, then $x\in \Omega \setminus A$, where $\Omega\setminus A \in \mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 0):

A probability measure is not defined on "outcomes" but on "events" which are special  sets of outcomes.

A probability space includes a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ which is a collection of subsets of outcome space $\Omega$ and probability measure $P$ is a function that has $\mathcal A$ as domain (not $\Omega$).

If we speak of the "probability of an outcome" then actually we are taking about the probability of event $\{\omega\}$ which only makes sense under the condition that $\{\omega\}\in\mathcal A$.

It might well be that for some or even for every $\omega\in\Omega$ we have $\{\omega\}\notin\mathcal A$.